# Irregularity of $\{b^ma^n: (m,n)=1\}$ using Nerode

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

> Let $L=\{b^ma^n \mid \text{$m$ and $n$ are coprime} \}$. Using Nerode's theorem, prove that $L$ is irregular.

From Nerode's theorem I know that $L$ is regular if and only if the number of equivalence classes of $R_L$ (the relation defined in Nerode's theorem) is finite, so I need to prove that there are infinitely many equivalence classes.

The first thing that came to mind from $L$'s definition is using Dirichlet's theorem, hence I tried:

Let $w_{m, i}=b^ma^i$, ($m,i$ are coprime), and I prove that for $j\ne i$, ($m, j$ coprime), $$w_{m, i} \not R_L w_{m, j}$$
Let $z=a^{m+ni}$, ($n$ an integer promised by Dirichlet's theorem such that $m+ni$ and $m$ are coprimes), so $$w_{m, i}z = b^ma^{m+ni+i}= b^ma^{m+(n+1)i}\in L$$
and $$w_{m, j}z = b^ma^{m+ni+j}\not\in L$$
But this isn't necessarily true as $m$ and $m+(n+1)i$ might not be coprime and $m$ and $m+ni+j$ might be.

I know from previous exercises that I need to find $w_i$ and show that for a word $z$ $$w_iz\in L\text{ and }w_jz\not\in L \space\space (i\ne j)$$ and therefore there are infinitely many equivalence classed, but I find coprimality difficult to handle.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4437077/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/151050/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be the set of all primes. Show that the words $\{b^p : p \in P\}$ belong to different equivalence classes.